# File link appears when Chatter Feed is hidden and Page is refreshed

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter, chatter-feed, chatter-file

I have a requirement to hide the File Link in chatter feed. I have a VF Page and I am able to do this using the below code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
               $j = $.noConflict();
               $j(document).ready(function(){

                    $j('#publisherAttachContentPost').hide();  
               });
                </script>

<div id="chatter-container">
        <chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!Object1__c.id}" showHeader ="true" oncomplete="refreshStatus()" reRender="statusPanel" />
    </div>
```

But this works only when show Feed is clicked and the record is opened or refreshed. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

If the Show Feed is not clicked earlier
[image]

and if you open or refresh the record and click on Show Feed, then the File link still appears. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Can some please tell me what am I missing.

Comment: Got it fixed by making changes in the Page Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Made changes in Page Layout to fix it.

When you go to the Page Layout in Quick Actions you can remove the File option and save the layout.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little so that it might be of use to others later down the line?

Comment: When you go to the Page Layout - in Quick Actions you need to remove the File and save it. This worked for me.